# Loop counter not interpreted as number

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to create 32 small boxes next to each other that each contain its current index.

|0|1|2|3|...|31|

This code makes me trouble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=0pt, 
    box/.style={outer sep=0pt, draw, thick, minimum height=0.6cm}]

    \node[box](0) {0};

    \foreach \i in {0, 31} {                
        \node[box, right=of \i] (\i + 1) {\i+1};    
    }

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have the impression that {\i+1} is not interpreted, but instead i+1 is actually written for a given i. How can I make tikz to compute i+1 and to assign the result as a name or label?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your impression is right. One way to enforce evaluation is to use `\numexpr`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=0pt, 
    box/.style={outer sep=0pt, draw, thick, minimum height=0.6cm}]

    \node[box](0) {0};

    \foreach \i in {0,..., 31} {                
        \node[box, right=of \i] (\the\numexpr\i + 1\relax)
        {\the\numexpr\i+1\relax};    
    }

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The less hacky way, though, is to use evaluate.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=0pt, 
    box/.style={outer sep=0pt, draw, thick, minimum height=0.6cm}]

    \node[box](0) {0};

    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \nexti using {int(\i+1)}] in {0,..., 31} {                
        \node[box, right=of \i] (\nexti)
        {\nexti};    
    }

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a `pic` version thereof.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=0pt, 
    box/.style={outer sep=0pt, draw, thick, minimum height=0.6cm},
    pics/boxrow/.style 2 args={code={
    \node[box] (#1){#1};
    \foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \nexti using {int(\i+1)}] in
    {#1,\the\numexpr#1+1,...,#2} {                
        \node[box, right=of \i] (\nexti)     {\nexti};    
    }
    }}]
 \path (0,0) pic{boxrow={0}{30}}
 (0,-1) pic{boxrow={5}{18}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Even another solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=0pt, 
    box/.style={outer sep=0pt, draw, thick, minimum height=0.6cm}]

    \node[box](0) {0};

    \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially 0), count=\ni] in {1, ..., 31} {                
        \node[box, right=of \lasti] (\ni) {\ni};    
    }

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A variation of [Ignasi's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/495482/118714) where you can easily change upper and lower bound of the `\foreach`-range.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance=0pt, 
  box/.style={outer sep=0pt, draw, thick, minimum height=0.6cm}
]
  \foreach \i [remember=\i as \lasti (initially a)] in {0, ..., 31} {
    \if a\lasti
      \node[box](\i) {\i};
    \else
      \node[box, right=of \lasti](\i) {\i};
    \fi
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To be honest, I do not understand your behavior.

Answer (score 0):

An even simpler solution is to reuse the names.

```
\documentclass{standalone}% too big for article
\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{positioning}% not needed

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=0pt, 
    box/.style={outer sep=0pt, draw, thick, minimum height=0.6cm}]

    \node[box](0) {0};
    \coordinate (last) at (0.east);

    \foreach \i in {1, ..., 31} {                
        \node[box, right] (\i) at (last) {\i}; 
        \coordinate (last) at (\i.east);
    }

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```